# When should I capitalise eucalyptus or other genera?

Tags: capitalization, terminology

I'm reasonably familiar with the capitalisation and italicisation rules that govern scientific names, but am a bit confused about capitalising, or not, the name of a genus, e.g. *Eucalyptus* when used in a sentence. Which of the following is correct?

> Where do Eucalyptus trees come from?
>   Where do eucalyptus trees come from?

Is this correct:

> "Are eucalypts indigenous to Australia?"

Comment: Yes, your last sentence would be correct - you don't need to capitalize "eucalypts".  Normal English capitalization rules apply, of course: DO capitalize it at the beginning of a sentence, or in the case of a pub called The Fookin' Eucalypt. (I would totally drink there.)

Answer (score 6):

We don't write *Oak tree*, and there's no reason to write *Eucalyptus tree* in non-specialist writing. However, in scientific writing it is customary to capitalise the first letter of a genus (but not the first letter of a species), so botanists would describe the tree native to Australia as *Eucalyptus obliqua*.

Comment: So, do we capitalize it because it is the genus ("oak" being the common term rather than "Quercus"), or don't capitalize it because we are not using it in a scientific context?

Comment: @BillyNair: Both.

Comment: GAH!! So it is fine either way? the sentence: "I watched a koala climb the Eucalyptus tree." would be ok? or should I save the capital for talking about scientific terms?

Comment: @BillyNair - You could say "I watched a koala climb the eucalyptus tree" (lower case), or "I watched the *Phascolarctos cinereus* climb the *Eucalyptus obliqua*."  You don't need to capitalize the genus (in a non-scientific context) UNLESS it is not the same as the common name (capitalize Quercus, don't capitalize oak.)

Comment: OK, that is what I was thinking. Just got confused in the translation.